# How to convert string in Date format?

Tags: apex, date, convert

I have a string like this : '20170206'

I need to convert it into a date like that : 06/02/2017

```
 String birthdayDate = '20170206';
 Date dt = Date.parse( birthdayDate);  
 system.debug(' Parsed Date is ' + dt );
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to parse the String like this:

```
String birthdayDate = '20170206';

Integer year = Integer.valueOf(birthdayDate.substring(0, 4));
Integer month = Integer.valueOf(birthdayDate.substring(4, 6));
Integer day = Integer.valueOf(birthdayDate.substring(6, 8));

Date dt = Date.newInstance(year, month, day);

System.debug(dt.format()); // 2/6/2017
```

Also, please, note, that I assumed that `02` is the month and `06` is the day. So if I took it wrong, replace expressions for month and day like:

```
Integer month = Integer.valueOf(birthdayDate.substring(6, 8));
Integer day = Integer.valueOf(birthdayDate.substring(4, 6));
```